# Azure automation job OData $filter

Tags: azure, odata, azure-automation, azure-runbook

**Background**

- I have an application which get list of runbooks jobs using [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/job/listbyautomationaccount)
- I would like to apply $filter on properties parameters(see JSON in the end). Parameters is of type `IDictionary<string,string>`

**Issue**

- $filter works fine for most of the properties but fails for `IDictionary<string,string>`
- This is what I am trying `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/XXX/jobs?$filter=properties/parameters/any(keyValue: keyValue/owner eq 'Adam@test.com')&api-version=2015-10-31`
- Request fails with error `{
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "Could not find a property named 'owner' on type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair_2OfString_String'."
  }`

**Question**

- Is it possible to filter what I am trying?
- If yes, then what I am doing wrong?

**JSON response on which I want to apply filter**

```js
"value": [
        {
            "id": "/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/XXX/jobs/XXX",
            "properties": {
                "jobId": "XXX",
                "runbook": {
                    "name": "HelloWorldRunbook"
                },
                "schedule": null,
                "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                "status": "Completed",
                "creationTime": "2018-06-17T05:44:12.197+00:00",
                "startTime": "2018-06-17T05:44:21.227+00:00",
                "lastModifiedTime": "2018-06-17T05:44:43.43+00:00",
                "endTime": "2018-06-17T05:44:43.43+00:00",
                "jobScheduleId": "7fc134ac-d8bd-464e-b041-6e6b50f83f0c",
                "runOn": null,
                "parameters": {
                  "Owner": "Adam@test.com",
                  "mailBox": "test_mailbox@test.com"
             }
            }
 ............removed for brevity
```

Comment: I try to test the [List Job By Automation Account Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/job/listbyautomationaccount), but there is no `parameters` returned in the response body. I test with powershell command in the runbook with script that required parameters. Would mind sharing your  runbook script demo code that could get the parameters in the response?

Comment: @TomSun Thanks for your response! I assumed that there is `parameters` property somewhere in backend because they are returned when you try this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/job/get).  Sorry if my assumption does not make sense?

Answer (score 0):

When I try to run [List Job By Automation Account Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/job/listbyautomationaccount), there is no properties `parameters` returned in the response body.

> If yes, then what I am doing wrong?

```
  ...
  "parameters": {
                  "Owner": "Adam@test.com",
                  "mailBox": "test_mailbox@test.com"
             }
   ...
```

But according to you mentioned responsed json format, the parameters properties is an object not  a dictionary, so you could use `$filter=properties/parameters/Owner eq 'Adam@test.com'` to do that if you make sure that parameters is existed.

```
 Get https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/{automationAccountName}/jobs?api-version=2015-10-31&$filter=properties/parameters/Owner eq 'Adam@test.com'
```

Comment: Parameters property is not an object but IDictionary<string,string>